# get value of global variable updated in function in a separate function php

Tags: php, function, global-variables

i am trying to get the value of a php global variable in a fucntion after updating it in another function .Here is a sample of the php file

```
<?php
$category;
if (isset($_POST['continue'])) {
  checkId();
}
if (isset($_POST['continue1'])) {
  getDataNo();
}
function checkId()
{
  global $category;
  $category = "Test 1";
  echo ($category);
}
function getDataNo()
{
  global $category;
  echo $category;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <h2>Form A</h2>
  <form action="" method="POST">
    Id:<br>
    <input type="text" name="id">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="continue" value="Continue">
    <br><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="continue1" value="Continue 1">
    <br><br>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Am fairly new to PHP but what i am trying to achieve is initially the value for category is empty then in the first function **checkId** the value of the category will be updated in this case to **Test 1** then in the second function **getDataNo()** i want to echo out the new value of the category

Comment: This won't work. Not because either of the functionn does not work. But because you will never call _both_ functions in a single request. Your html form will only post one of the two values, never both.

Comment: You need to understand that separate requests to your php scripts are strictly separate. There is no connection between them, _unless_ you create one. That is typically done by using a "session". You can store a value in such a session. Which also means that you can stop using a global variable (which is bad style anyway). You can read about php sessions in the documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: ok thanks so no way to get the variable from function 1 and store somewhere or anywhere could be an html text on the same page then when the second button is clicked the variable is retrieved, because like i said am new to PHP but that why i have two button for the two function so i think they are separate requests to the php scripts

Comment: Those two buttons will send separate requests, because you defined them as submit buttons.